# Firebase error "invoke virtual method" on null object when object should be initialized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I keep getting a null object error and my app crashes, though I don't see why there should be an error. I have looked at other examples and those are all the same, and don't help with my issue. My issue occurring although from what I have seen it shouldn't be. The code is:

```
package com.example.matthew.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;



public class makecharact extends Activity {
    Button retur, mak, cont;
    FirebaseUser user;
    DataSnapshot datasss;
    Spinner spinner2;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String id;
    DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.charlist);
        Intent task = getIntent();
        retur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.returnToLast);
        mak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.make);
        cont = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Conti);
        addListenerOnButton();
        ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                datasss = dataSnapshot;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        Log.d("Test Point 1", "Got to line 61 at the least");
        id = user.getUid();
        int check = 0;
        boolean done = false;
        Log.d("User ID", id);
        while(done == false) {
            String sCheck = Integer.toString(check);
            if (datasss.hasChild(id)  == true){
                if(datasss.child(id).hasChild("Character List") == true){
                    if (datasss.child(id).child("Character List").hasChild(sCheck) == true) {
                        list.add(datasss.child(id).child("Character List").child(sCheck).getValue().toString());
                        check = check + 1;
                    }else{
                        done = false;
                    }
                }else{
                    list.add("No characters");
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataset = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        dataset.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataset);
        Log.d("Test Point 2", "Got to line 77 at the least");
    }





    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        cont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                String stats;
                stats = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                myRef.child(id).child("Current Character").setValue(stats);
                Intent TaskIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainScreen.class);
                startActivity(TaskIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        mak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                Log.d(TAG, "Moving");
                Intent TaskIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), spinner.class);
                startActivity(TaskIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        retur.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Moving");
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My logcat shows:

```
05-31 21:05:39.802 14318-14318/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.matthew.myapplication, PID: 14318
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matthew.myapplication/com.example.matthew.myapplication.makecharact}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.hasChild(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.hasChild(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.example.matthew.myapplication.makecharact.addListenerOnButton(makecharact.java:81)
                                                       at com.example.matthew.myapplication.makecharact.onCreate(makecharact.java:45)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7223) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

I have tried a lot though I still don't get why it isn't working. Any help is appreciated, even if it is it's already been solved on another post (which i couldn't find with a link to said post. Thanks

Comment: have you set correct permissions on firebase to read data at that database reference ?

Comment: @NishantDubey Yep. Have to be authenticated and the very first thing the user does is sign in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will return Null pointer exception Because your variable `dataass` not initialized.
and its is initialized only when `ValueEventListener()` is triggers `onDataChange()` So you need to execute every thing inside the `onDataChange()`

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            datasss = dataSnapshot;myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    Log.d("Test Point 1", "Got to line 61 at the least");
    id = user.getUid();
    int check = 0;
    boolean done = false;
    Log.d("User ID", id);
    while(done == false) {
        String sCheck = Integer.toString(check);
        if (datasss.hasChild(id)  == true){
            if(datasss.child(id).hasChild("Character List") == true){
                if (datasss.child(id).child("Character List").hasChild(sCheck) == true) {
                    list.add(datasss.child(id).child("Character List").child(sCheck).getValue().toString());
                    check = check + 1;
                }else{
                    done = false;
                }
            }else{
                list.add("No characters");
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataset = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
    dataset.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataset);
    Log.d("Test Point 2", "Got to line 77 at the least");
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, as I thought. I was then getting an error from my spinner but i realized I didn't set it to be the spinner in my activity, in fact I never set it, but thank you for your input.

Comment: Okay if you felt helpful then accept this answer as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get firebase data like this.

```
    DatabaseReference databaseTracks;

    List<Track> tracks;

 databaseTracks = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tracks").child(intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.ARTIST_ID));



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseTracks.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                tracks.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Track track = postSnapshot.getValue(Track.class);
                    tracks.add(track);
                }
                TrackList trackListAdapter = new TrackList(ArtistActivity.this, tracks);
                listViewTracks.setAdapter(trackListAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it is overly complicated, though I might be able to do something now, because it gave me an idea, I put my while loop in the onDataChange(), and that might prevent the problem. I dont know yet, Im going to try it now